# sudo ./VMware-ovftool-4.3.0-13981069-lin.x86_64.bundle /var/tmp/scllpy5Nh: line 8: ./VMware-ovftool-4.3.0-13981069-lin.x86_64.bundle: Permission denie

Tags: centos6, ovf

I am trying install *ovftool 4.3* on my **centos 6**; but initially I had installed ovftool 4.2; but for now requirement I need ovftool 4.3, but getting error when I run this **sudo  ./VMware-ovftool-4.3.0-1398106-lin.x86_64.bundle**, this is the same cmd type I used to install ovftool 4.2

How to update ovftool to 4.3?

this is the error
bash-4.1$ sudo ./VMware-ovftool-4.3.0-13981069-lin.x86_64.bundle
/var/tmp/scllpy5Nh: line 8: ./VMware-ovftool-4.3.0-13981069-lin.x86_64.bundle: Permission denied

Thanks in Prior!

I couldn't find any way of uninstalling ovftool 4.2 and then installing 4.3; I am in dilemma, can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

It was simplest of trick I was missing out! I didn't had enough permissions to run ovftool 4.3 so I was getting this error; just used `chmod` command to change permissions to execute, and then I was simply able to run using ./VMware-ovftool-4.3.0-13981069-lin.x86_64.bundle

Note: To uninstall older versions of ovftool use: `sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-ovftool`